# How Do I Wire Battery?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, amplifier

I’m working on a little project of building a wireless speaker box, I’m getting some help from my dad as he used to build and sell speakers for DJ’s as a hobby so that side is all sorted but what I’m having a bit of worry with is the correct way to wire the battery.

I would need the battery to charge from an input on the side of the box and provide power to the amplifier, what I was wondering is if it would be as simple as getting a 12/24v input [Example](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/221446846939) and connecting it to the terminals on the battery and if I am able to connect the amplifier to the terminals too or would need anything extra, I was thinking about using this battery or similar: [Battery](https://www.batteryclerk.co.uk/injusa-f1-go-kart-24v-12v-7ah-scooter-battery.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIwZKbq9n21AIVTrHtCh1RBw2HEAQYAyABEgJNyPD_BwE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AGM battery that you linked to requires a special charger made for that type of battery. You cannot directly connect it to a 12 volt supply for charging.

If you use an improper charging scheme, there is the possibility that the battery will vent hydrogen which is quite explosive. The battery life will also be greatly shortened.

More advanced circuits bring in 12 volts to operate the electronics and have a special charger for the battery that operates off the same 12 volts. These systems often will use a technique called diode isolation that ensures the battery is used only when the 12 volts is not available.

The OP asked in comments about battery types for this application. For the sake of replication, I will walk through a little bit of the engineering first.

The amplifier sited is a 50 watt per channel, 2 channel amp. But this is not the power the amp will require on a continous basis. In sound engineering, there is a metric called the crest factor.  This expresses the peak to average power ratio of the source. This can vary according to genre, artist, etc. Bands like the Eagles and the Beatles had crest factors approaching 20 dB. That is a 100 to 1 power ratio.

So if we want to be a purist, we should run the amplifier at 1/100th on the average of its maximum power to leave headroom for undistorted peaks of these artists. In the case of a 50 watt amp, this means running it at 0.5 watts average. Take note though that most amps have significant distortion when operating at their stated maximum output power.

For the sake of this example, let's set the average power at 5 watts (allowing a 10 dB crest factor). So two channels is then 10 watts. If we assume 75% efficiency for the class E amp and BT, this is a total power requirement of ~ 15 watts.

Now we need to determine how long it needs to run before being recharged. I will use 4 hours for this example. 15 watts times 4 hours is 60 watt-hours. If the power source is 12 volts, this is 5 amp-hours (60 watt-hours / 12 volts).

Battery amp-hours ratings are over a 20 hour period. If we shorten that period, the capacity is reduced. For a 4 hour discharge period, derate the battery by 30%. This brings the battery requirement to ~7 amp-hours. So with these numbers your chosen battery should work. But you have all the assumptions and math so you can rework things to suit your preferences.

You could also consider using 4 Lithium Ion cells of a similar amp-hour rating. These too require special charging but it may be simpler to have them removable in order to plug them in a bespoke charger. With removable batteries, you can always have a second set to plug in while one set is charging.

Comment: Hi thanks for the info Glenn, are there any types of battery that you would recommend for this task? I don’t want to to be too bulky as it will already be heavy to move but I still want a decent amount of life out of it.

Comment: That really depends upon what it is powering. Can you post specs for the amp, etc?

Comment: It would be something similar to https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/162194825631 if not that itself, powering 2 x 50W full range speakers.

Comment: I will update my answer with some thoughts on this.

Comment: It sounds like a great father-son project. Have fun! Post back with any questions.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was just wondering while too if you know much about tactile switches? I’m going to be purchasing this board https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B018FX57IS/ and was hoping to attach some momentary toggle switches to put on the box itself instead of leaving the PCB exposed, is it possible for me to solder the wires for the switches rather than de-solder them from the board and solder in the switches?

Comment: In general that should work. Make sure to twist the pairs of wires together for each switch and try to keep them as short as possible.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for all your help! Unfortunately I can’t upvote in electrical engineering yet but you’re getting too answer!

Answer (score 0):

You should include fuses one for charging and one for discharge.

Do you want the amp to work while charging? If not, then you need a disconnect to turn the amp off while charging - there are some connectors / jacks that do this, check out the connector suppliers.

What have you considered to control charging or turn it off once the battery is charged?

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for helping out. I didn’t really think about that I was going to add a charging indicator so it could then be unplugged but that’s not safe at all. It’s a good job I asked I would have ended up blowing my face off! I think I would definitely want to be able to charge and power at the same time too.

Comment: So charge and run at the same time is simple, just choose a charging connector that cannot be fitted the wrong way.

Comment: Great thanks :) what would you recommend for the auto cut off on charging as not to have to monitor it hen unplug?